# MongoDB C# - ISupportInitialize methods are not called

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using the MongoDB C# driver to talk to a Mongo Atlas instance.
I'm restructuring the schema of a few documents and I want to use ISupportInitilize to read some extra elements and convert them to the new expected schema.

This is the old document definition:

```csharp
public class ImageDocument : DocumentBase, ISupportInitialize
{
    [BsonExtraElements]
    public Dictionary<string, object> ExtraElements;

    //Other elements omitted for brevity.

    public string AzureImageId { get; set; }
    public string AzureImageUrl { get; set; }

    public void BeginInit()
    {
    }

    public void EndInit()
    {
    }
}
```

Here is the new document definition:

```csharp
public class ImageDocument : DocumentBase, ISupportInitialize
{
    [BsonExtraElements]
    public Dictionary<string, object> ExtraElements;

    //Other elements omitted for brevity

    public AzureImageInformationPage Original { get; set; } //Original, as uploaded

    public void BeginInit()
    {
    }

    public void EndInit()
    {
        if (Original == null)
        {
            Original = new AzureImageInformationPage {
                AzureImageId = ExtraElements.GetValueOrDefault("AzureImageId").ToString(),
                ImageUrl = ExtraElements.GetValueOrDefault("ImageUrl").ToString()
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Now, for some reason the EndInit method is never called, even though the MongoDB documentation states it should happen [automagically](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.7/reference/bson/mapping/#isupportinitialize).

I'm using the following code to interact with the MongoDB C# driver:

```
public async Task<IList<T>> RetrieveAll<T>() where T : DocumentBase
{
    return await GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable().ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<IList<T>> RetrieveWhere<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query) where T : DocumentBase
{
    return await GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable().Where(query).ToListAsync();
}

public async Task<T> RetrieveSingle<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query) where T : DocumentBase
{
    return await GetCollection<T>().AsQueryable().SingleOrDefaultAsync(query);
}    

private IMongoCollection<T> GetCollection<T>() where T : DocumentBase
{
    //Slightly modified from the real code, so it's easy to read.
    var collectionName = typeof(T).Name.Replace("Document", string.Empty);

    //Database name is hardcoded for now.
    var database = mongoClient.GetDatabase("MyDb");

    return database.GetCollection<T>(collectionName);
}
```

How do I get the MongoDB driver to call the ISupportInitialize methods?
Thanks in advance for helping me out.

Comment: Could you try in another sample project using the latest version of driver and see if  there's the same problem?

Comment: I can easily change te version of the driver in my current project. I've tried 2.5, 2.6 and 2.7. All of them have the same issue.

Answer (score 6):

I've found the issue.

As of writing, initialization is only supported when compiling against .NET 4.5.
I'm using .NET core 2.0.

See [this issue](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-2138) on the MongoDB Jira, and line 131 to 150 in the [BsonClassMapSerializer](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/v2.5.0/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/Serializers/BsonClassMapSerializer.cs) class.

Hopefully the MongoDB team will add support for serialization in .NET core soon.